# Get num rows from mysql query php

Tags: php, mysql

It's just my first post here in stackOverflow.

Could you tell me how it's possible that my code returns `1` in variable `$rows` even when the email is not listed in my database?

**Code**

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM konta  
WHERE email='".$fieldsFromForm['email']."'";
if($result = $this->dbo->query($query)){
    $rows = $result->num_rows;
    if($rows>0){
        return USER_NAME_ALREADY_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are querying for `count(*)`. That query always returns one row! The count you are looking for is the data of that row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you select a count that will give you one row only containing `0` on no rows or a higher number if there are rows with that mail.

Use this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM konta WHERE email='".$fieldsFromForm['email']."'"
```

Optionally you can use `COUNT(*) as cnt` and get the associative result and go with `$row->cnt`, but I'd prefer the first option